# Determining FSM states hint

Tags: state-machines

I want to get the idea behind determining states of a FSM. I would appreciate a hint for the following problem as to where to look for the states.

"A FSM should send out a signal to open a door. If you are authorized by wearing an ID, a sensor detects you and the door opens (out to in, always). However, between 9PM and 6AM, the door does not open if you're inside (night lock). At other times, the FSM also opens the door from in to out."

Where do you start? Are night and day the states, or open and closed, are 'states' a combination of those?

Comment: It doesn't even sound like FSM. A simple state-less logic.Well, would depend on the other problem details. For example - should it "memorize" that you are inside, or it has a sensor telling you are inside?

Comment: night and day are your only two states in your example, that is if you really want to use a Finite-State-Machine to accomplish this. However FSM is a Computer Science / SW Engineering concept, and not in any way related to electronics what so ever, so this question does not belong on EE.SE

Comment: @Vinzent I would consider Night and Day inputs, and not states.. again, lacking details.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I don't agree, I would considder the inputs to be; "Has valid ID?" and "Is inside or outside?", but more importantly, this question is not EE related and does not belong on this site.

Comment: @Vinzent You do not agree because we don't have the details :) If Day and Night are determined by external sensor or clock - then it is definitely input. If the clock is internal to FSM - then it is state.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Okay I do agree that depending on details that we don't have, your view could be just as good as mine, however I assumed the clock to be internal to the FSM, as specific times were quoted, and not ambient light intensities or what have you ;). It is also worth noting that FSM can be implemented both with action taking place continuously depending on the current state, and/or with action taking place at the transition between states, and depending on which type of FSM you are implementing, both could be either states or inputs.

Comment: Where does my question belong then? This is part of digital design, so EE was my best guess. The goal is to let the FSM ouput a signal that opens the door

Comment: The sensor knows inside from outside position

Comment: So inputs: authorized/inside/outside/nighttime (all boolean) and output: open door

Comment: No, this is not part of digital design, then you don't understand either what an FSM is, or you don't understand digital design, sorry. FSM is not a term that we use in EE, because it is not something that you implement in glue-logic, ie. in digital electronic designs. FSM is again a computer science subject, to do with programming, that could be in whatever programming language you prefer so I would refer you to one of the SE sites related to programming/SW engineering or to stack overflow.

Comment: If all these are inputs, then there is no FSM needed. Just a combinatorial logic.

Comment: "If all these are inputs, then there is no FSM needed. Just a combinatorial logic." Exactly, he does not understand what an FSM is I think.. This question should be closed.

Comment: There's Digital Design books with chapters about FSM and implementations in HDL. State machines most certainly are a part of that.

Comment: I don't disagree that you can use combinatorial logic to solve this. It's a different paradigm though. FSM's use state info and allow for more advanced designs using state logic, memory and output logic.

Comment: No, it is not a different paradigm, it's a different level of complexity One is not designing sequential logic where combinatorial is sufficient, and one cannot design combinatorial logic where sequential is needed (because it is impossible).

Comment: Thus using a FSM for something easily solved by combinatorial circuits is not impossible. It's at most redundant, but it has a possible answer. You have to start somewhere, I would like to start here.

Comment: Also, judging by the dictionary, it is. Thanks for your time guys. I'll try my luck in another way.

Comment: This is more complex than it may at first seem. If a doorway is going to control the direction that a user moves, then it must actually be **two doors** with a space in between, with only one door unlocking at a time. Now you need an FSM to control the locking and unlocking of these two doors, based on whether the user is outside, between the doors, or inside -- and which door he's attempting to pass through.

Comment: In case of conflict - with people at both sides - that is? In the simpler case of only one actor, what states would you propose then?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I worked this out on the basis of the state representing the signal status, whether there is any (*SIGNAL*) or none (*NULL*).
*ID* represents the recognition of the ID Card, *DAY* represents the state of the time being not between 9 PM and 6 AM, and *IN* represents the status of the worker being inside.
Hope this helps... If it seems wrong, please correct me.

**Errata**: *ID || (IN && not(DAY))* should be replaced by *not(ID) || (IN && not(DAY))*

Comment: Would it be interesting to find the conditions for which the door should close when opened, rather than immediately going back to null?

Comment: You could have a condition as the output of SIGNAL. When it is satisfied, the FSM goes to NULL, else it remains at SIGNAL.
Such a condition can be (TIME_DONE) where TIME_DONE is a boolean describing whether a timer has passed a set period of time after the NULL-->SIGNAL crossover or not.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I think you should first decide which kind of FSM do you want to design: A **Moore machine** or a **Mealy machine**.

Choosing which one is better four your project depends on system requirements and on the final desired implementation.

Anyway, there's no specific rule to define how many states you would have. It depends on how you want to organize your states and deal with input/output changes.

In your case, a good design in my opinion would have **two states**: "day" and "night". With **ID** and **Inside/Outside** as your inputs.

Comment: Would it make sense to use a Moore machine where the states are the door being open and closed, which automatically yields the signal?

Comment: Yes, I think you could try an implementation like that; As I said, it's really up to you how you want to design your system. In this case, it also depends on the desired door behavior.